# Dynamic names of rows in MySQL

Tags: node.js

`Node.js` MySQL query returns a RowDataPacket.

```
RowDataPacket {
  inc: 10,
  id: 1,
  login: '123'}
```

It's possible to get access to values by field names: `result[0].inc`. But what to do if field names are `id_1, id_2, id_3, ... id_i` and I want to create loop and get access to them. I can't simply do `result[0].id_1, result[0].id_2, ...` because it's dumb if `i` is big.

```
RowDataPacket {
  id_1: 10,
  id_2: 1,
  id_3: '123',
  ...
  id_i: '567'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `[]` to get to the field - `object.foo` and `object['foo']` are equivalent..

```
for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    var colName = 'id_' + i;
    var value = result[0][colName];
}
```